# Why is Logout working as a GET Request and not a POST Request?

Tags: python, django, authentication, logout

This is the html file

```
<a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a>
<form action="{% url 'logout' %}" method="POST" id ="logout">
 {% csrf_token %}
<input type ="hidden">
 </form>
```

This code in view.py.

```
def logout(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print("post-request")
        auth.logout(request)
        return redirect('index')
    else:
        print(request.method)
        auth.logout(request)
        return redirect ('index')
```

Why is the Logout a GET request and not a POST request ?
I made some changes in projects based on the documentation and could not understand why you can be successfully logged out with a GET request.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/

Comment: That html file has a logout **link** and also a logout **form**.  The form does not have submit button, so presumably you're clicking on the logout link, which is of course a GET.

Comment: The Logout form has method="POST", so why ´would it still be get ?

Comment: The form does not have a submit button, and no visible input elements, so I don't think the form will even appear on the page.  The only visible thing should be the link.

Comment: 1. Why is it possible to logout without using the {% csrf_token %} 2. Is there some problem with using a Logout as a GET request ?

Comment: csrf_token is used only on forms.  But, as I said above, you must be clicking on the logout link, so you're not using a form.

Answer (score 2):

your **Logout** is in `<a>` tag that has a link, which sends GET request, and logout form is outside of that `<a>` tag. and you are currently using your link, so form is not in used for logout.

you may need something like this:

```
<form action="{% url 'logout' %}" method="POST" id ="logout" class="nav-link">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="submit" value="Logout">
</form>
```